# Allow reassignment of [Win] + [num+] or completely remove Magnifier on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, uninstall, hotkeys

I'd like to use hotkey <kbd>Win</kbd> <kbd>num +</kbd> for my audioplayer but this combination is bound to Windows' Magnifier. Anyone have an idea how to fix it (unbind or completely remove magnifier)?

(This problem is directly related to [How to disable Utility Manager (Windows Key + U)](https://superuser.com/questions/19085/how-to-disable-utility-manager-windows-key-u))

Comment: This is directly related to http://superuser.com/questions/19085/how-to-disable-utility-manager-windows-key-u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm always reading about how [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) can do this sort of thing, but it does mean having a program constantly running in your taskbar,

You can use AHK to do a massive variety of things for you so you may be able to live with it for all the features.

[Autohotkey Key Remapping](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm)

Comment: The problem that ever if it will work I won't be able to bind this to some other program, only to Autohotkey

Comment: {#NumpadAdd::Run notepad} (ignore the {}), this will run notepad when pressing [WIN]+[NUM +]. If you don't want AutoHotKey to be installed simply compile it as an EXE (right click the .ahk and choose compile)

Comment: @HardQuestions as in Slackers example you can use autohotkey to rebind a hotkey to run some other application such as notepad.  I think you can even bind hotkeys to other hotkeys.

Comment: Thatnks - that's an option to bind hotkey to other hotkey.