# How to disable utilities manager

Tags: keyboard

How do I disable utilities manager in windows ? I can not use computer to type anything

I am using Chrome but this doesn't work on explorer either

Comment: You can't unless you perform a hack like http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-windows_programs/how-to-disable-utility-manager/52b76edd-287b-e011-9b4b-68b599b31bf5?msgId=1d9ebc5b-c67b-e011-9b4b-68b599b31bf5 or modify the rights to the file http://superuser.com/questions/19085/how-to-disable-utility-manager-windows-key-u which begs the question why you want to disable it.  Please clarify what you meant exactly by saying "It doesn't work on explorer eitehr"

Answer (score 1):

Utility Manager is located in the WINDOWS\system32 directory. The file is utilman.exe. Just renaming the file to something else will stop it from being launched.

Alternatively You can :-
1)  Open task manager --> In Processes tab stop the process utilman.exe
2)  Or you type msconfig in Run --> Disable utility manager in Services and Startup tabs.